# Installing Solr 4.x.x on Apache 2.4.x httpd server

Tags: php, apache, solr, apache2.4

I work on Windows 7 OS and I have Apache httpd server (2.4.6) installed in it. I would like to install Apache Solr 4.7.0 on Apache 2.4.6 httpd server.

Is there way to install Solr on Apache httpd server? Because most of which I found on the web is for Tomcat server.

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/if-you-want-to-configure-solr4.html

http://jorgedoig.com/setting-up-tomcat-7-and-solr-with-xampp-on-windows-7/

http://amac4.blogspot.sg/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html

I am using Apache httpd server for my web application implemented in PHP and I need to integrate Solr for search capability.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr needs something like Tomcat, Jetty etc. to run, it cannot run within Apache httpd server.

You can run Solr within Tomcat and then connect it to Apache httpd by using something like `mod_jk` or a reverse proxy.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thanks for the reply. Could you provide me with some details or links so that I can look into? coz im totally new to solr

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall    http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat